# a href _self not working on modified <button>

Tags: html, css

Around this modified `<button>` there is a a href that should open the link in the same window, this however does not happen. The only way to open this link is to add `target="_blank"` instead. **How can this be solved?**

```css
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) 
}

button.circle {
  width: 65vh;
  height: 65vh;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

button.circle::after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  background: teal;
  border-radius: 100%;
  animation: breathe 4.5s ease infinite alternate running;
}

@keyframes breathe {
  from { transform: scale(1); }
  to { transform: scale(1.4); }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_self"><button class="circle centered">Click me</button></a>
```

Comment: Buttons can't be descendants of anchors

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to nest a button into an anchor tag according to HTML5 spec [document](http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element).

The following can't be nested into an anchor tag:

```
<a>

<audio> (if the controls attribute is present)

<button>

<details>

<embed>

<iframe>

<img> (if the usemap attribute is present)

<input> (if the type attribute is not in the hidden state)

<keygen>

<label>

<menu> (if the type attribute is in the toolbar state)

<object> (if the usemap attribute is present)

<select>

<textarea>

<video> (if the controls attribute is present)
```